# delete pending app 'New Version' in iTunes connect

Tags: xcode, app-store-connect

I started a new version of my app in iTunes connect and I do not want and/or need it - how do I get rid of it?  Currently in the status of 'Waiting For Upload'.

Comment: I've the same question. Have u get any solution?

Comment: nope, I ended up creating a completely new app actually, which is not what I wanted to do but.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I read the iTunes Connect Developer Guide, googled, and asked in IRC, and this is what I got:

You can delete an application when it is in one of the statuses below:

> Prepare for upload
>
> Waiting for upload
>
> Invalid Binary
>
> Developer Rejected
>
> Rejected
>
> Metadata Rejected
>
> Developer Removed from Sale
>
> Removed from Sale

So you can't remove it while being in sale. I have an app with a similar situation to yours, and I tried removing it from all stores in sale, to get that `delete app` button in App Information section, and even tried clicking on the button, but the warning told me that it will remove the whole app from iTunesConnect, and the app store.
[image]

Asking from other developers, I ended up in ignoring the pending version, till I submit it. Seems that there's no way for removing the pending version.

**Update** for those who may not recognize it from the screenshot here, this post is about removing the unwanted new version that you've created in your iTunesConnect, but have noticed that you don't want it.

Comment: That must be new, because that was not there for sure, or at least a year and a half ago - thanks!

Comment: It appeared after I removed the app from all stores; and actually I just noticed how late this response is to your question! Anyhow hope it helped.

Comment: you must have to remove it from all stores first - that totally makes sense

Comment: @user102008 Yes! And the answer is about removing the "new version" as well. Read the posts and *check the screenshots* carefully before down-voting. Also see the -4 scored answer and its comment below!

Answer (score 5):

While it is not possible to delete a pending version, you can always change the version number in order to comply with what version you want to upload next. Having a pending version can be used to upload testing build and distribute it using TestFlight.

Comment: Good point. I was fixated on removing the version and creating a new and did not think that the version number could be changed. But it could, and it was fast and easy. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I just got myself into a similar situation. I had forgotten to include my in-app purchase and had clicked the submit binary button. There didn't seem to be a way to do it. So I called Apple Dev Support and after awhile they figured out that the best way for me to do it was to submit a binary and then *reject the binary*.

Then I can add my in-app purchases.

Answer (score 0):

On the Version Information page, there are some links on the right one of which is 'Binary Details'.  I clicked on this and was then able to click on 'Reject this Binary'.

After doing that, the status of my new version when back to 'Ready to Upload Binary'.

Answer (score -6):

On iTunes Connect navigate to the *Manage Your Applications* module, select the application you would like to delete, then on the *App Information* page choose `Delete App`

Comment: I don't want to delete the entire app - just the pending version.