# How do I remove an iOS app version in iTunes Connect?

Tags: app-store-connect

[image: iTunes connect screenshot - see highlighted link]

How do I remove the highlighted link?

I saw this post: [delete pending app 'New Version' in iTunes connect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7237554/delete-pending-app-new-version-in-itunes-connect). The UI seems different from what we have now.

Answer (score 0):

Finally figured it out. Go to "My Apps" then click on your app and make sure the "App Store" tab is selected. Under "Pricing and Availability" there will be a section: "Last Compatible Version Settings". There you can deselect previous versions that you don't want users to be able to download.

[image]